# Matching optional groups with lookahead in JavaScript regex

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-greedy, regex-lookarounds

I'm trying to solve a string matching problem with regexes. I need to match URLs of this form:

```
http://soundcloud.com/okapi23/dont-turn-your-back/
```

And I need to "reject" URL of this form:

```
http://soundcloud.com/okapi23/sets/happily-reversed/
```

The trailing '/' is obviously optional.

So basically:

- After the hostname, there can be 2 or 3 groups, and if in the second one is equal to  *"sets"*, then the regex should not match.
- *"sets"* can be contained anywhere else in the URL
- *"sets"* needs to be an exact match

What I came up so far is `http(s)?://(www\.)?soundcloud\.com/.+/(?!sets)\b(/.+)?`, which fails.

Any suggestions? Are there any libraries that would simplify the task (for example, making trailing slashes optional)?

Comment: Should `http://soundcloud.com//okapi23/dont-turn-your-back/` match or not?

Comment: Definitely not, there should always be at least 1 word character between slashes.

Comment: What about a `.`? Should this match `http://soundcloud.com/./okapi23/dont-turn-your-back/`?

Comment: No, just word characters, i.e. `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`

Comment: What about a hyphen? Should this match `http://soundcloud.com/-/okapi23/dont-turn-your-back/`? I ask because your examples contain hyphens.

Comment: Basically, each group has to start with a letter of the alphabet, and can contain the aforementioned word characters.

Comment: Ok that's a bit more clear now. So just to check that I've understood it correctly, should `http://soundcloud.com/a-/b--/c---/` match?

Comment: Yeah sorry, add hyphens to the list. Hyphens and underscore can only function as word separators though (i.e. `--`, '__' and `-_` are not allowed anywhere).

Comment: You're question is not well defined. Is this URL to be picked out from a larger text or does it comprise the whole string? Is the host always the same? How about the `https:` or `ftp:` schemes? Can there be a query and/or a fragment? With regex questions, you need to very precisely define _exactly_ what you wish to match (and not match).

Comment: Should this match `http://soundcloud.com/0/1/2/`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that the OP wants to test to see if a given string contains a URL which meets the following requirements:

- URL scheme must be either `http:` or `https:`.
- URL authority must be either `//soundcloud.com` or `//www.soundcloud.com`.
- URL path must exist and must contain 2 or 3 path segments.
- The second path segment must not be: `"sets"`.
- Each path segment must consist of one or more "words" consisting of only alphanumeric characters (`[A-Za-z0-9]`) and multiple words are separated by exactly one dash or underscore.
- The URL must have no query or fragment component.
- The URL path may end with an optional `"/"`.
- The URL should match case insensitively.

Here is a tested JavaScript function (with a fully commented regex) which does the trick:

```js
function isValidCustomUrl(text) {
    /* Here is the regex commented in free-spacing mode:
    # Match specific URL having non-"sets" 2nd path segment.
    ^                          # Anchor to start of string.
    https?:                    # URL Scheme (http or https).
    //                         # Begin URL Authority.
    (?:www\.)?                 # Optional www subdomain.
    soundcloud\.com            # URL DNS domain.
    /                          # 1st path segment (can be: "sets").
    [A-Za-z0-9]+               # 1st word-portion (required).
    (?:                        # Zero or more extra word portions.
      [-_]                     # only if separated by one - or _.
      [A-Za-z0-9]+             # Additional word-portion.
    )*                         # Zero or more extra word portions.
    (?!/sets(?:/|$))           # Assert 2nd segment not "sets".
    (?:                        # 2nd and 3rd path segments.
      /                        # Additional path segment.
      [A-Za-z0-9]+             # 1st word-portion.
      (?:                      # Zero or more extra word portions.
        [-_]                   # only if separated by one - or _.
        [A-Za-z0-9]+           # Additional word-portion.
      )*                       # Zero or more extra word portions.
    ){1,2}                     # 2nd path segment required, 3rd optional.
    /?                         # URL may end with optional /.
    $                          # Anchor to end of string.
    */
    // Same regex in javascript syntax:
    var re = /^https?:\/\/(?:www\.)?soundcloud\.com\/[A-Za-z0-9]+(?:[-_][A-Za-z0-9]+)*(?!\/sets(?:\/|$))(?:\/[A-Za-z0-9]+(?:[-_][A-Za-z0-9]+)*){1,2}\/?$/i;
    if (re.test(text)) return true;
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Instead of `.` use `[a-zA-Z][\w-]*`  which means "match a letter followed by any number of letters, numbers, underscores or hyphens".

```
^https?://(www\.)?soundcloud\.com/[a-zA-Z][\w-]*/(?!sets(/|$))[a-zA-Z][\w-]*(/[a-zA-Z][\w-]*)?/?$
```

To get the optional trailing slash, use `/?$`.

In a Javascript regular expression literal all the forward slashes must be escaped.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the Regex works perfectly! Accepting @ridgerunner's answer because it's more detailed.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to go with regex pattern

```
^https?:\/\/soundcloud\.com(?!\/[^\/]+\/sets(?:\/|$))(?:\/[^\/]+){2,3}\/?$
```